# ConstraintLayout braking after displaying Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am currently working on an android app, and I'm having an issue with **displaying XML layout**
In Android Studio, everything looks fine, but in the VM it doesn't look too good.

**This is how it looks in Android Studio:**

[image: Screenshot here]

**And here is how it looks like when it's displayed in VM:**

[image: Screenshot here]

I should probably mention that it is supposed to be a pop up window

**Here is XML code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_grey"
        android:padding="20dp"
        >

    <android.widget.Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Cancel"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:outlineProvider="none"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.widget.Button
            android:text="Set"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SaveTimer"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_dark"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <View
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_dark"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.32" />

    <TextView
            android:text="0 h"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hourValue"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.514" />

    <TextView
            android:text="0 min"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/minuteValue"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hourValue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondValue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground" />

    <TextView
            android:text="0 sec"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondValue"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="231dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.514" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here is code from the Main Activity:**

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String ipAddress = "192.168.1.59";
    private int port = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Setting background color
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(30,30,30));

        // hiding bottom navigation bar
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        // Initiation request
        new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"volume").execute();

        // Click event for Volume Up button
        ImageButton VolumeUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.VolumeUpButton);
        VolumeUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"volume up").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for Volume Down button
        ImageButton VolumeDown = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.VolumeDownButton);
        VolumeDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"volume down").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for Volume Up Lot button (lot means volume does up for about 33 %)
        ImageButton VolumeUpLot = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.VolumeUpLotButton);
        VolumeUpLot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"volume up lot").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for Volume Down Lot button (lot means volume does down for about 33 %)
        ImageButton VolumeDownLot = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.VolumeDownLotButton);
        VolumeDownLot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"volume down lot").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for ScreenShot Button
        ImageView ScreenShotButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ScreenShotButton);
        ScreenShotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"screenshot").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for Lock Button
        ImageView LockScreenButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.LockScreenButton);
        LockScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"lock").execute();
            }
        });

        // Click event for Mute Button
        ImageView MuteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MuteButton);
        MuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"mute").execute();
            }
        });

        // Enter press event for ippAddress input
        EditText ipAddressInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddress);
        ipAddressInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    ipAddress = ipAddressInput.getText().toString();
                    Log.i("Ip Address changed", String.valueOf(ipAddress));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        // Enter press event for port input
        EditText portInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
        portInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portInput.getText().toString());
                    Log.i("Port changed", String.valueOf(port));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        // Click event for Shutdown scheduler
        ImageView shutdownScheduler = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ShutdownTimer);

        View parent = (View) findViewById(R.id.ParentViewFroPopUp);
        parent.setClickable(false);

        //Overlay animation init
        ///TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) parent.getBackground();

        shutdownScheduler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // treba dorobit to dialogove okno a tam mat nastavenia a vlastne tlacidlo na zrusenie timeru
                //int time = 2000;
                //new ConnectionWithServer((Activity) MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this,ipAddress,port,"timer " + time).execute();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null );
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                        popupView,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.setOverlapAnchor(true);

                Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.Cancel);



                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                        //transition.reverseTransition(5000);
                    }});

                //transition.startTransition(5000);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
                parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#90000000"));

            }});


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding,

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
```

to your last `TextView`(`@+id/secondValue`) component.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation you have forgotten to add some contraints to your views.
In order that they are display as you would like, try to add all four constraints when possible.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/quantum_black_100"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/places_text_white_alpha_26"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/SaveTimer"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground" />

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/SaveTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:text="Set"
        android:textColor="@color/quantum_white_100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Cancel" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hourValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 h"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/minuteValue"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minuteValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 min"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondValue"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hourValue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 sec"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/minuteValue"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/TimerValluesBackground"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```